# Inputting to an R function both the dataframe and column reference into dcast()

Tags: r

I'm trying to extract the following code as a function, where movies_sub is a dataframe and Director is a column name.

```
library(tidyr)
library(reshape2)
movies_sub$Director <- strsplit(movies_sub$Director,"(\\s)?,(\\s)?")
unnested <- unnest(movies_sub)
movies_sub <- dcast(unnested, ... ~ Director, fun.aggregate = length)
```

Here is my attempted function:

```
toDummyVars = function(df, col) {
  df[,col] = strsplit(df[,col],"(\\s)?,(\\s)?")  # split by comma
  unnested = unnest(df)
  df = eval(dcast(unnested, ... ~ col, fun.aggregate = length))
}
```

I've figured out how to represent movies_sub$Director as df[,col].

However, how do I have the column name "col" recognized when I execute dcast in the 3rd line of toDummyVars()?

Answer (score 0):

We can change the third line with `paste`

```
toDummyVars = function(df, col) {
   df[,col] = strsplit(df[,col],"(\\s)?,(\\s)?")  
   unnested = unnest(df)
   dcast(df, paste0("... ~ ", col), length)
}
```

Comment: is your 3rd line using paste  `dcast(df, paste0("... ~ ", col), length)` equivalent to my function's 3rd line `df = eval(dcast(unnested, ... ~ col, fun.aggregate = length))` ?    I'm still getting the same error with your code.  Thanks.

Comment: @DRozen I did tested with an example before posting it and it was working.  Of course, I don't know how your data looks like, so it is hard to say how you are getting error.

Answer (score 0):

```
toDummyVars <- function(df, colName) {
  dfTemp = df
  dfTemp$colName <- strsplit(dfTemp[,colName],"(\\s)?,(\\s)?")  # separate by commas
  unnested <- unnest(dfTemp) # convert to long format with each feature separated with correct corresponding Profit.  
  dfTemp <- dcast(unnested, Title + Profit ~ `colName`, fun.aggregate = length, value.var = "colName")  # convert to binary vectors with one-hot encoding.  
  return(dfTemp)
}
```

The problem was that colName needed to be recognized with `` as in `colName` in line 4 of the function.  Also column name needs to be passed to hte function as a string.  eg.

```
genreBin = toDummyVars(moviesForBin, "Genre")
```

see 
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/formula.html